# Grouping similar items in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I'm trying to do something, and I'm wondering if this can be done in Pandas or if there's a better tool for the job (currently I'm just using straight python for it). Here is the starting data:

```
# We have a listing of files for the movie Titanic
# And we want to break them into groups of similar titles,
# To see which of those are possible duplicates.
import pandas as pd
titanic_files = [
    {"File": "Titanic_HD2398.mov",  "Resolution": "HD", "FrameRate": 23.98, "Runtime": 102},
    {"File": "Titanic1.mov",        "Resolution": "SD", "FrameRate": 23.98, "Runtime": 102},
    {"File": "Titanic1.mov",        "Resolution": "HD", "FrameRate": 23.98, "Runtime": 102},
    {"File": "Titanic.mov",         "Resolution": "HD", "FrameRate": 24.00, "Runtime": 103},
    {"File": "MY_HD2398.mov",       "Resolution": "HD", "FrameRate": 23.98, "Runtime": 102}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(titanic_files)
```

And I want to group these files by similar data, never collapsing the row-level data, for example:

1. Step 1 -- Group by Resolution

   ```
   ---- HD ----
   File               Resolution             FrameRate              RunTime
   Titanic_HD2398.mov HD                     23.98                  102
   Titanic1.mov       HD                     23.98                  102
   Titanic.mov        HD                     24.00                  103
   MY_HD2398.mov      HD                     23.98                  102

   ---- SD ----
   File               Resolution             FrameRate              RunTime
   Titanic1.mov       SD                     23.98                  102
   ```
2. Step 2 -- Group by FrameRate

   ```
   ---- HD -----------------------
    +----------- 23.98 ------------
   File               Resolution             FrameRate              RunTime
   Titanic_HD2398.mov HD                     23.98                  102
   Titanic1.mov       HD                     23.98                  102
   MY_HD2398.mov      HD                     23.98                  102

    +----------- 24.00 ------------
   File               Resolution             FrameRate              RunTime
   Titanic.mov        HD                     24.00                  103


   ---- SD -----------------------
    + ---------- 23.98 ------------

   File               Resolution             FrameRate              RunTime
   Titanic1.mov       SD                     23.98                  102
   ```

And at the end, I want to basically have individual data frames for each of the smallest groupings. In python, I am currently doing this with the following data structure:

```
{
   'GroupingKeys': [{File1WithinThatBucket}, {File2WithinThatBucket}, ...]
}
```

For example:

```
{
   'HD+23.98' + [{'File': ...}],
   'HD+24.00' + [{'File': ...}]
}
```

Also, please keep in mind that there are about 10-15 fields that I'm grouping on, I've just included two in the above question, so this approach needs to be pretty generalized (also, some of the match criteria are not exact, for example runtime might be bucketed to something like +/- 2 seconds, some values may be null, etc.).

And back to the original question: can something like this be done in Pandas, and if so, How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas' `groupby` seems the tool to be used, it can take as many groupers as needed and they can be of type list, series, column_name, index_level, callable... you name it

For example you can do:

```
df = df.groupby(
    [
        'Resolution', df.FrameRate//0.02 * 0.02,
        pd.cut(df.Runtime, bins=[45, 90, 95, 100, 120])
    ]
).File.apply(list)
```

Which will return a DataFrame with a unique MultiIndex of 3 levels and one column, each row containing a list of filenames.

You can also get the full rows for each group if for some reason, with other data, you want to split one df into many and keep it that way.

```
for group_id, group_rows in df.groupby(...):
    # group id are tuples each with a unique combination of the grouping vectors
    # group_rows is a df of the matching rows, with the same columns as df
```

Comment: where should the closing `]` be? I get `invalid syntax` from above (no closing `]`).

Comment: It was fine as I typed it, made an edit to show the structure more clearly

Comment: great, thanks for the update. Just a couple questions on the answer: what is `.File` -- I've never seen that before? And second, why the `//0.02 *0.02` hack?

Comment: All the columns of a dataframe can be accessed as attributes(unless the column name is a defined method for df as sum, mean, etc.) returning a series. The floor division was just an example of using modified series as a grouper without the need of modifying the original df.

Comment: oh, I see! I thought `.File` was a method on the dataframe, but I see that's just a field that I have...that makes much more sense now.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to accomplish the above in Pandas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408544/instantiate-a-class-in-a-groupby-apply-method