# Instantiate a class in a groupby method

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following class for a file:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, file_name, md5):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.md5 = md5
    def do_something(self):
        ...
```

Would it be possible to create this object directly from a `groupedby` mapping in pandas. For example something like this:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['resolution','media_type', 'asset_type'])
df_grouped_2 = df_grouped.apply(lambda x: File(x['file_name'], x['md5']))
print (df_grouped_2)
```

And I should be able to get something like:

```
# resolution  media_type  asset_type
# HD          Video       Feature       [<obj1>, <obj2>, ...]
#                         Promo         [<obj1>]
#                         Trailer       [<obj1>, <obj2>, ...]
```

How could I do something like the above (and are there any additional methods I need to add on the `class`, such as `__hash__` ?)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  There is probably a simpler way to do whatever you want.

Comment: @anon01 I have a `dict` from my previous question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408061/how-to-create-a-dict-object-mapping-in-an-aggregation-field, now I'd like to see if that can be extended into an object where I can add its own methods and such.

Comment: Can you shed any more light onto your underlying goal?

Comment: @anon01 really just an extension of having a `dict` type. The ability to more easily add custom methods and do type checking for that item.

Comment: @RichieV `obj1` would be the equivalent of doing something like `obj1 = File(file_name=..., md5=...)`. The custom methods would be extremely specific...but basically I just want to have the custom object and work with that once all the data is aggregated.

Comment: I suppose you could define a function (not a class) that takes arrays and returns objects and use [groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply). A single call to `.apply` loop through the groups and pass the filtered rows to your function, which MUST return a single row, e.g. a single object or a list of objects. To return all rows instead of one use `.transform` instead of `.apply`... that's all I can think with as much detail you provide

Comment: @RichieV I see, would you want to post an answer showing your approach and what might be a better way that how I'm currently thinking of doing it?

Comment: I'm happy to help if you provide an example of your code to get obj1 and obj2, or at least the logic of how the will be constructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this is a solution. You can instantiate objects in the apply method. I created an example class and dataframe.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': list('abbaabcc'),
    'group2': list('abababab'),
    'a': [1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4],
    'b': [3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4]
})
df
```

Output

```
  group group2  a  b
0     a      a  1  3
1     b      b  2  4
2     b      a  1  2
3     a      b  2  3
4     a      a  3  4
5     b      b  2  5
6     c      a  3  3
7     c      b  4  4
```

Create Objects in apply

```
df.groupby(['group','group2'])[['a','b']].apply(
    lambda x: [Test(e[0],e[1]) for _,e in x.iterrows()])
```

Output

```
group  group2
a      a         [<__main__.Test object at 0x7f5351df0390>, <__...
       b                [<__main__.Test object at 0x7f5351df03d0>]
b      a                [<__main__.Test object at 0x7f5351df0450>]
       b         [<__main__.Test object at 0x7f5351df0490>, <__...
c      a                [<__main__.Test object at 0x7f5351df0550>]
       b                [<__main__.Test object at 0x7f5351df04d0>]
dtype: object
```